# Select records with values up to and over (but only one over) another value?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have data such as...

```
 ID    | Amount
-----------------
 1     | 50.00
 2     | 40.00
 3     | 15.35
 4     | 70.50
```

etc. And I have a value I'm working up to, in this case let's say 100.00. I want to get all records up to 100.00 in order of the ID. And I want to grab one more than that, because I want to fill it up all the way to the value I'm aiming for.

That is to say, I want to get, in this example, records 1, 2, and 3. The first two total up to 90.00, and 3 pushes the total over 100.00. So I want a query to do that for me. Does such a thing exist in MySQL, or am I going to have to resort to PHP array looping?

**Edit**:
To put it in English terms: Let's say they have $100 in their account. I want to know which of their requests can be paid, either in toto or partially. So I can pay off the $50 and the $40, and part of the $15.35. I don't care, at this point in the program, about the partialness; I only want to find out which quality in any way.

Comment: Provide an example of how you're using it -- for testing against, or that you want a rolling total...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is possible

```
 set @total:=0; 
 select * from
 (
   select *, if(@total>100, 0, 1) as included, @total:=@total+Amount 
   from your_table 
   order by id
 ) as alls
 where included=1
 order by id;
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks. I had a previous version of this where it was done in PHP (with stuff like "apply min(remaining, amount), if (remaining = 0) break"), and I'm much happier with MySQL doing the math rather than looping it through PHP til the account runs out of money. :)

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the last sentence: doesn't mysql [`sum`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php) cut it?

Comment: I want the individual records, not the total amount possible... I may have written it strangely with that "if". I know they have $100 in the account, I want to know which records can pay up to that.