# Getting rows until a certain condition is met in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit, aggregate-functions

Basically I have a table which has attachments. Simple table: ID, Name, Size and UploadedDate. I want to get the last x rows that in total, are less than 2 GB.

So, collect all rows in DESC order of UploadedDate until I have 2GB of total file sizes, then eliminate the rest.

Actually I need the inverse of that. So, I need to get all the attachment that are not part of the first 2 GB. I have advance experience in MySQL but right now it seems like I have a blank on this. I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky hint:

```
SELECT items.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as id, 100 as size
  ORDER BY id DESC
) items, (SELECT @total:=0) as init
WHERE (@total:=@total+size)+0 <= 200;


+----+------+
| id | size |
+----+------+
|  4 |  100 |
|  3 |  100 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPD**

Essentially the same, but probably more efficient:

```
SELECT items.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as id, 100 as size
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as id, 100 as size
) items, (SELECT @total:=0) as init
HAVING (@total:=@total+size)+0 <= 200
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

THe idea is that instead of `items` there should be your table.

Comment: I think this is close, but you should not using the UNION as you need to repet from row 1 to row Z. Why not you use the @total as a sum counter, then impose a HAVING?

Comment: @arjreal, I did not understand why I should not have used UNION (I used in to emulate an example table). Concering HAVING, I have not noticed that the condition is checked after the order is applied. So yes, it will be at least more readable and seemingly more efficient.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, what you have demonstrate is assuming there are only certain rows to match (which is 4 in your answer), but the actual rows is an unknown. In order to get rid of UNION, you can use the counter + HAVING to filter.

Comment: this is an example :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454960/select-records-with-values-up-to-and-over-but-only-one-over-another-value/4455019#4455019 (but is not using having)

Comment: @arjreal, once again, the UNION here is just an example table of 4 rows, so that you could try the example in MySQL console without table creation. Instead of `items` subquery there can be any other subquery or table.

Answer (score 0):

You could work out the possible size of each row by adding up the space requirements for the data type of each field and then use this to work out how many rows are 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM attachments t1, attachments t2
WHERE t2.UploadedDate >= t1.UploadedDate
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING sum(t2.Size) > 2GB
```

to select attachments to delete.

**DISCLAIMER** while it's standard sql it WILL be slow, as it's Ω(n^2) worst case for table with n rows. Use @newtover's solution.

In this case you might be better off by using stored procedure and looping over the attachments while summing up their sizes.

And for lost postgres souls here's solution equivalent to @newtover's but using window funcion:

```
SELECT outer_t.ID
FROM (
    SELECT t.ID, sum(t.Size) s
OVER (ORDER BY t.UploadedDate DESC)
FROM attachments as t
) as outer_t
WHERE outer_t.s > 2GB
```

Comment: this is going to end up in a huge cartesian product inbetween

Comment: @newtover that's why i mentioned the stored procedure. didn't know that there are hacks that allow one to define counter inside the query ;)